# Case insensitive check for role in HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, https, roles, user-roles

The `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` class has a method called `isUserInRole`. I use this to check if a user has, for example, the `admin` role. However, that method is case sensitive. So, if the role in the request was `Admin` or `ADMIN`, then `isUserInRole("admin")` would be false. I use the `isUserInRole` method in a number of places accross multiple applications to check for a number of different roles.

Is there a way to achieve the `isUserInRole` functionality case-insensitively that does not require checking each different possible case combination with `isUserInRole`?

Comment: Why? You have trouble spelling your role names consistently?

Comment: There are multiple versions of a third party authentication service that I am using in different environments, one of which lowercases role names, while the other preserves case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could implement a filter that wraps requests using a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` - implement your `HttpServletRequestWrapper` to override the `isUserInRole()` method to make it case-insensitive (eg, configure all roles in upper-case, test role params by converting to upper-case).

A quick search will find plenty of `HTTPServletRequestWrapper` examples...

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiie.html

Just map multiple role names to the admin role:

```
<servlet>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <role-link>admin</role-link>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
        <role-link>admin</role-link>
    </security-role-ref>
</servlet>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Comment: The call to `isUserInRole` is used to execute different code paths on rest endpoints based on role. We already have this kind of setup in our web.xml for access restriction.